# Find the count of repetitions of a specific word in 68000 files, each file of 24 mb approximately

Tags: vba, shell

In a folder I have 68000 files, i have to find the count of repetitions of a specific word in all those files. One file can have any number repetitions of the same word. Each file is approximately 24 mb. I am trying to code this in VB script. It is taking very long time (>30 mins) to find to read each file line by line.
Could you suggest a faster way or a tool to do this.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Why is this question tagged java ?

Comment: Have you run your numbers? To read 68000 files of 24MB each in 30 minutes you need a transfer-rate of about 906MB/s. That means you have to use a fast SSD to just do your I/O in the time you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to follow the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). This is used by `grep` so I'm quite convinced this should be efficient enough for you.

Answer (score -1):

You asked for a faster way, OR a faster TOOL to do this.

I would suggest using MythicSoft FileLocator Pro, or Lite.  The lite version is free for commercial use.

https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite

This will give you a count of repetitions of a specific word in all those files, plus much more.

I am in no way affiliated with MythicSoft..